# Transfer DNSSEC signed zones on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dnssec

I'm transferring zones between different Google Cloud Platform accounts which have been signed using DNSSEC. I've put the new zone into DNSSEC transfer state but when I try to load the DNSKEY into the new zone I am get an 'invalid value' error.

The old DNSKEYs are being retrieved by `dig -t dnskey`, I've tried entering the results with and without the spaces inserted in the keys by dig, same result.

I've tried both '256 3 8 AwE...' like the placeholder sample in the form and '256 3 RSASHA256 AwE...' as is shown for the current key when I attempt to edit it, also verifying my old keys match the length of my new keys for both the ZSK and KSK. Same result for both, always an input error.

The [manual](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/dnssec-config#migrating-to) does not indicate further steps, but maybe something is left out.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from trying to **replace** the new KSK/ZSK, they must be in addition to the existing keys.